# Error Raspberry ./program invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, godot

Help!!!

`pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/Linux/x32 $ ./game.x86
/lib/ld-linux.so.2: No such file or directory`
(Это было из-за неправильной компиляции)

А вот это новенькое
NEW ERROR

`./program invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error`

Comment: raspberry на процессорах с архитектурой ARM, на нем невозможно запустить бинарники откомпилированные под intel x86

Comment: Формальная причина описанного — на архитектуре ARM динамический линкер называется по-другому, поэтому нужный и не нашёлся. Другое дело, что если бы его имя и совпадало, это ничего бы не дало, потому что архитектура процессора совершенно другая, см. комментарий @Mike

Comment: Этот файл - это игра скомпилированная на godot. Я смог запустить сам годот на raspberry, но проект скомпилированный для него не могу запустить, вот новая ошибка
`./program invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error`

Действовал по этому гайду [тык_и_на_гитхабе](https://github.com/crabcrabcam/godot/releases/tag/2.1.4-stable-export)

Comment: @dirrm сравните, что́ показывает команда file на вашу программу и на какой-нибудь /bin/bash

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev 
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/Raspberry2 $ file game2.x86
game2.x86: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract

pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/Raspberry2 $ file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=3e5e2847bbc51da2ab313bc53d4bdcff0faf2462, stripped

Comment: @dirrm мне-то оно зачем? Я не предлагал мне показывать. Вы сравнили, всё поняли, сделали выводы: зип запускать на исполнение вряд ли имеет смысл.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev У меня вроде получилось теперь нормально, но хз что с этим дальше делать
 pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/Rasp3/debug $ ./game3.x86 -d
Usage: ./game3.x86 [options] [scene]
Options:
-path [dir] : Path to a game, containing engine.cfg...

ERROR: try_open_pack: Pack version newer than supported by engine: 1
At: core/io/file_access_pack.cpp:169.
error: Couldn't load game path '.'
ERROR: free_static: Condition ' !MemoryPoolStatic::get_singleton() ' is true.
At: core/os/memory.cpp:59.
Если знаешь что с этим делать, подскажи пожалуйста